# SQL json_object producing duplicate values

Tags: mysql, sql, json, json-arrayagg

This is what i need to achieve:

```
{"id":1,
"work":[
    {
        "name":"Pied Piper3"
    },
    {
        "name":"Pied Piper"
    }
],
"awards":[
    {
        "title":"Digital Compression Pioneer Award"
    }
]}
```

This is what i am getting

```
{"id":1,
"work":[
    {
        "name":"Pied Piper3"
    },
    {
        "name":"Pied Piper"
    }
],
"awards":[
    {
        "title":"Digital Compression Pioneer Award"
    },
    {
        "title":"Digital Compression Pioneer Award"
    }
]}
```

My query:

```
select json_object('id',basics.resume_id, 
    'work',JSON_ARRAYAGG(json_object('name', work.name)),
    'awards', JSON_ARRAYAGG(JSON_OBJECT('title', awards.title))
    ) from basics
        left join work on basics.resume_id = work.resume_id
        left join awards on basics.resume_id = awards.resume_id where basics.resume_id = 1
```

I have added two rows of work for resume_id = 1 but only 1 row of awards for resume_id = 1.But I still get as many number of awards in result as per the number of works for resume_id =1

Comment: Does your  data come back as nulls for awards as you are expecting, without the JSON_ARRAYAGG(). Can you post the output of your query using only the Ids?

Comment: Please, edit your post and give table schema and sample datas

Comment: Try `'awards', JSON_ARRAYAGG(DISTINCT JSON_OBJECT('title', awards.title))` , this would work in mariadb, in mysql I'm not sure, or are you using postgresql? Please set the correct tags and only the relevant.

Comment: @h.m.i.13 DISTINCT did not work. MySQL produced an error.